# cakephp + phpunit + gitlab continuous integration

Tags: mysql, cakephp, phpunit, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm looking for help with my tests in cakephp + phpunit + gitlab-ci.

I defined my test/fixtures like this: `public $import = ['model' => 'MyModel'];` to avoid having to redefine the tables schema in the fixture, and have out of sync/wrong code.

I understand that what it does is to look for the live db and use that information to generate the tables in the test db, but what about if there is no live db?

I'm trying to automate my testing in gitlab / continuous integration environment, and there they provide you a mysql container **with a single db** to run your tests. If I have a single DB, i will not be able to have both a main connection and the testing db, right?

I was thinking on having a create-db-for-tests.sql and imprort that script BUT I understand that running a test with a fixture will remove the table, so I would need to create it again and again on every test.

I could not use the gitlab mysql service and install mysql in the testing container to have 2 databases, like in dev,  but I would need to populate the other DB with some script too, and that's the same as defining the db structure in the fixtures.

How can I solve this problem?

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something came out from my mind after I read your question.

1. If you don't have live db, there might be two possibility which is
   you may have staging db or your application don't have DB.
2. According to your second question related about **If I have single DB**, I would say No. Because, you could have two connections.

e.g

```
 public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'foge',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8mb4',
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'test_foge',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8mb4',
);
```

When creating a fixture you will mainly define two things: how the table is created (which fields are part of the table), and which records will be initially populated to the table.

I think, you can populate your script with this. Because this is mysql command. But, say honestly i haven't try it before.

`mysql -u jenkins -pcakephp_jenkins -e 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test_foge; CREATE DATABASE test_foge; CREATE TABLE users; CREATE Table posts';`

And the last one is you can populate data before you run it and I guess you already knew it.

```
class ArticleFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

    public $fields = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
        'title' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false),
        'body' => 'text',
        'published' => array('type' => 'integer', 'default' => '0', 'null' => false),
        'created' => 'datetime',
        'updated' => 'datetime'
    );

    public function init() {
        $this->records = array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'title' => 'First Article',
                'body' => 'First Article Body',
                'published' => '1',
                'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ),
        ); 
        parent::init();
     }
}
```

As my personal perspective, good idea to drop and re-create the database before each build as well. This insulates you from chained failures, where one broken build causes others to fail.